# why is HTTP/3 traffic faster when wrapped to an SSH tunnel?

Tags: nginx, curl, http3

I am experimenting with HTTP/3, I compiled both nghttpx and nginx with HTTP/3 support and deployed them to an EC2 instance. I also compiled curl 8.4.0 with HTTP/3 support and use Firefox 118.0.2 as an alternative client. What I noticed is that downloading a 100MB test file with HTTP/2

```bash
curl --http2 -o /dev/null -v https://my.domain.name:8443/100mb.test -k
```

has an average speed of about 5 MB/s with my internet connection.
Using HTTP/3 instead

```bash
curl --http3 -o /dev/null -v https://my.domain.name:8443/100mb.test -k
```

runs at around 200 KB/s only. Even more strange, if I create an SSH tunnel to my machine with

```bash
ssh -L 8443:localhost:8443 my.domain.name
```

and then try an HTTP/3 download through the tunnel

```bash
curl --http3 -o /dev/null -v https://localhost:8443/100mb.test -k
```

speed goes back to 5MB/s. I've tried both `nginx` and `nghttpx` as servers and `curl` and `Firefox` as clients and the behavior is the same.

What can be the explanation for this behavior?

EDIT:
SSH protocol uses TCP, so it's not possible to create a UDP tunnel or to forward UDP traffic, what I had experienced was simply curl failing to connect with TCP3 to the local 8443 and then falling back to HTTP/2

Comment: Looking at an [overview of HTTP/3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/3) I see the protocol is built on UDP. The differences here might be due to different routing between your instance and the CURL endpoint. That might explain why tunneling the connection fixes the performance issue, assuming you're running SSH over TCP. If you're able to configure the SSH tunnel to run on UDP, that would be an interesting test.